# Diet planner software

Tags: gratis, linux, health, planning

I am looking for a good software to create meal plans and analyze their nutritional data. Here are the features I am looking for:

- Manage multiple diet plans
- A diet plan typically covers a couple of weeks
- Each day you have subitems: Meal1 (breakfast), Meal2 (snack), Meal3(lunch) etc.
- You should be able to add custom food with macro and micronutrients
- It should calculate for a given range (one meal, one day, some days, whole plan) a statistics of the nutritional data, total calories, micro and macro nutrients (average per day if you select multiple days)
- You should be able to create recipes out of some ingredients and include a certain amount of a recipe and other raw foods into a meal of a day.
- It should be free software
- It should run on linux (or also acceptable but not optimal: on windows or a web app).

Other features which would be great do have but are not necessary for me are:

- The ability to add pictures to recipes
- Have access to a nutrition database
- Since I am from germany, it would be even better if the database would be a german one
- A good printing support for the plans (maybe even a LaTeX export)
- Organize foods and recipes using tags or groups
- Make copies of plans/meals/recipes

All nutrition software I found so far is about tracking what you actually eat but not making plans. So tracking is not what I want but making plans.

Answer (score 1):

[MyFitnessPal](https://www.myfitnesspal.com/) is a calorie counter and fitness journal, but it has most of the features you are looking for.

I will go through the features in your list and try to analyze if they are available on MyfitnessPal.

1. **Manage multiple diet plans**: This is not a feature but you can simulate it by creating multiple accounts.
2. **Each day you have subitems**: Each day on MyFitnessPal is divided into breakfast, lunch, dinner and snacks.
3. **You should be able to add custom food with macro and micronutrients**: This is possible.
4. **It should calculate for a given range (one meal, one day, some days, whole plan) a statistics of the nutritional data, total calories, micro and macro nutrients**: I believe this is only possible in the paid version and choosing the range would not be as flexible as you want. But, I do not think that you will find something like this on a free app.
5. **You should be able to create recipes out of some ingredients and include a certain amount of a recipe and other raw foods into a meal of a day**: This is possible.
6. **It should be free software**: There is a free version with a decent amount of features compared to other apps.
7. **It should run on Linux (or also acceptable but not optimal: on Windows or a web app)**: There is a web app. This also gives you the ability to use multiple browsers to manage multiple diet plans on different accounts.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. Let me share some disadvantages of MyFitnessPal. The free version displays advertisements. I would prefer no advertisements. The premium version costs $49.99 / year or $9.99 / month. I would prefer a free app or a one-time purchase. The home screen displays a news feed, and I couldn't disable this in the settings. I would prefer no news feed.

Answer (score 0):

This app allows planning diet ahead based on nutrition value. https://nutritionanalyzer.app

It's quite different from what you request, but it serves the main purpose well.